# String converts to an integer instead of double

Tags: c, double

I want my function to convert a string to a double but if I type for example '22.4' it will output '22'. How do I get it to output a double?(USING fgets) I've read other questions that had answers saying use sscanf but is there a way for using fgets?

```
double getDouble(char message[]){

double val;
double var = 0.0;
char input[80];

do{
    printf("%s\n", message);
    fgets(input, 80, stdin);

    if (input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n'){
        input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
    }
    val = atof(input);

    if (val != 0.0){
        var = 1.0;
    }
    else{
        printf("Error. Please try again.(Only entering numbers is valid)\n");
    }
}while(var == 0.0);
printf("The result is: %f\n", val);

return val;


}
```

Comment: Try `%.1f` instead of `%f`.

Comment: still the same result

Comment: what string are you trying to convert?

Comment: let's say your input is a number with decimals (44.21231) it will only output 44

Comment: My code below seems to print out `44.2` for that string, is that what your after?

Comment: yes i will test your code

Comment: wow i guess your code works do you know why mine does not?

Comment: Could you post your entire code? So we can see how your calling `getDouble`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you're getting: http://ideone.com/gtmYeB

Comment: @RoadRunner I literally just call the function in main with a simple message "Please enter a double"

Comment: @JohnSmith See my code below.

Comment: What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: @RoadRunner: `%f` is fine for a double in `printf`. You mean `scanf`.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  2)

Comment: to avoid problems, the returned value from the call to `fgets() should be checked to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the `atof()` function does not detect errors, so 0.0 is a possible valid returned value.  You might want to use: `val = strtod( input, NULL );` Read the man page for `strtod()` for all the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example.

Some modifications:

- Using a `near_equal()` function, as testing equality of doubles is dangerous.
- Instead of using a double flag such as `var = 0.0`, why not just use an `int`?
- Checking the return value of [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) is always a good idea.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <math.h>

  #define BUFFSIZE 80
  #define EPSILON 1e-8

  double getDouble(char message[]);
  int double_equal(double a, double b);

  int
  main(void) {
      double num;

      num = getDouble("Enter a real number: ");

      printf("The result is: %.1f\n", num);

      printf("The number you entered was %g\n", num);

      return 0;
  }

  double
  getDouble(char message[]) {
      double val;
      char input[BUFFSIZE];
      int found = 0;

      do {
          printf("%s\n", message);
          if (fgets(input, BUFFSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
              if (input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n'){
                  input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
              }
              val = atof(input);

              if (!double_equal(val, 0.0)) {
                  found = 1;
              } else {
                  printf("Error. Please try again.(Only entering numbers is valid)\n");  
              } 
          } 
      } while (found == 0);

      return val;
  } 

  int
  double_equal(double a, double b) {
      return fabs(a-b) < EPSILON;
  }
  ```

Comment: well thanks for trying but it still does not work for some odd reason

Comment: There are no errors it runs fine it's just that if I put any decimals it rounds it to an integer

Comment: Hmmm that's strange. If I enter `4.21231`, I get `4.2` as the conversion.

Comment: ok so apparently your code works if i just copy and paste the whole thing but when I tried to implement it into my program it did not work

Comment: @JohnSmith, I didn't change much of your code. I just made some modifications.If you apply those changes, it should work just fine.

Comment: @John Smith No worries :)

Comment: @RoadRunner,  the limited output after the period is because of this in the printf() format string: `%.1f`  if you make that `%f`, then the default number of digits after the period will be displayed

Comment: @user3629249 fixed.